# Is there a word for positive distraction?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word "distraction" has generally negative or frivolous connotations, but shifting your mental focus can often be positive (you go on a walk and solve the hard problem, you spend a few days away from the office and you gain a new perspective, etc.).

> You should get away from it all, that will [insert the word] you.

Comment: What's meant by _tk_?

Comment: @Kit It was the placeholder for the word the OP is looking for.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I see. Just found out it means "to come".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "diversion" pretty much does what you want. But I agree that 'distraction' really shouldn't have a negative connotation. But it does and there's nothing we can do about that.

Comment: Actually it has both a negative and a positive one, it depends on the context where you use it.

Answer (score 9):

The word is exactly the same: **distraction**.

Starting from the verb **to distract**, there is one of its meanings where the verb gets the acception you meant, becoming reflexive though (**to distract oneself**). The definition is this one:

> Divert one's attention from something worrying or unpleasant by doing something different or more pleasurable.

Same goes for the noun, *distraction*:

> A diversion or recreation: *There are plenty of distractions such as sailing.*

In this case, distraction means something like "*take a break* from what stresses you". Hope this answers your doubts.

Comment: @downvoter: if you ever see this comment, would you please write the reason(s) for downvoting? It'd be nice to know, thanks!

Comment: Some people are always 'trigger happy' to downvote. Well, I upvoted yours. Your answer is good, maybe you can add source more :).

Answer (score 1):

In the example sentence you give, I might put *clear your mind*. But I agree with [Alenanno's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37910/is-there-a-word-for-positive-distraction/37913#37913) in general.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first one sounds like "breaking" - as in "taking a break." Going on a walk is a break.

But the second one ("go away for a few days and gain a new perspective") sounds clearly to me like *vacationing* (literally ["The action of leaving something one previously occupied"](http://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy&hl=en&tbs=dfn:1&source=hp&q=vacation)).  In other words, leave it and do something else - I've heard terms such as "put it on the backburner" but I don't have a single word for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "positive" could be defined in this case, but there are several words for "distraction" that is "positive".

> [Divertissement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/divertissement)
>   [Brouhaha](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brouhaha)

Also:

> Preoccupation
>   Amusement

Answer (score 0):

Recreation is a fine term for positive distractions I would daresay.

[FreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Recreation)

rec·re·a·tion  (rĕk′rē-ā′shən)
n.

1. Refreshment of one's mind or body after work through activity that amuses or stimulates; play.
2. An activity that provides such refreshment.